# Publication in industry

Tags: publications, phd, industry

I am not really sure how research works in industry. I am an early grad student and research is my passion. However, I do want to go into industry once I am done with my thesis.

But, I do want to continue to publish papers or patents with my job. As, I would be going to industry after a Phd, I would be working in a close field. Most of my advisor's students get positions in R&D wings of reputed companies. But, it seems like many of them stop publishing once they leave. I wanted to ask, if it is possible to collaborate with universities and professors and keep publishing during my work.

My area of work is in semiconductor physics and nanoscience.

Comment: See [Scientific output of researchers in industry and academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9648/scientific-output-of-researchers-in-industry-and-academia)

Comment: What is your field?

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [this answer tells my story about this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18309/4140) and may be helpful if you work in the mathematical fields.

Answer (score 2):

It depends heavily on the company. I know some companies that see publishing employees as a benefit and possibility for advertisement. Other companies are afraid that a competitor might steal the work. Thus, they often require that a patent is submitted beforehand and/or supervisors are required to check the paper for secret information. In general most companies do not think that publication is a great benefit and often do not support it, e.g., travel expenses.